# How to use !! in conjunction with replace_na in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider

```
b<-data.frame(s=c(1,4),v=c(3,5))
g<-"f"
b<-b %>% mutate(!!g:=NA)
b
  s v  f
1 1 3 NA
2 4 5 NA
```

I now want to replace the NA in the third column by 0 through the variable that contains the column name of the third column. So I did

```
> b %>% replace_na(b$(!!g),0)
Error: unexpected '(' in "b %>% replace_na(b$("
```

How do I replace the contents of the third column through using the variable (in this example, this variable is g) that contains the column name of the third column?

Comment: Just running the first bit produces an error `Error: object 'f' not found`

Comment: @camnesia Sorry. It should be g <-- "f"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace_na()` inside `mutate()` to just change your single vector.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

b <- data.frame(s=c(1,4),v=c(3,5))
g <- "f"

b %>% 
  mutate({{g}} := NA) %>% 
  mutate({{g}} := replace_na(!!sym(g), 0))
#>   s v f
#> 1 1 3 0
#> 2 4 5 0
```